# Split row based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

So, I've been sitting on this for quite a while(and pulling my hair) now and would really appreciate some help here. I've got some aggregated data in a dataframe like so,

```
CLASS_ID,ACH_MONTH(MM format),ACH_YEAR(YYYY format),FEES,PAY_TYPE
862424,06,2020,1000,Month
862425,04,2020,10000,Quarter
862426,02,2020,60000,Bi-Annual
```

(a).What I'm trying to do is to split a record into 3, whenever the `PAY_TYPE` is `Quarter`, based on following logic,

(i). Divide fees by the number of months in the Quarter i.ie., 3.

(ii). Apply the result as the new value of `FEES` for all the 3 splitted records with the `ACH_MONTH` being the individual month of the quarter for each record.

For Example,

Consider the 2nd record,

Here, `ACH_MONTH` is 04 means April which is present in the Quarter2.

Now devide value of `FEES` with 3 i.e., 10000/3 = 3333.33.

Now Split the record to 3 with each value `ACH_MONTH` denoting each respective month of the Quarter2 like so,

```
862425,04,2020,3333.33,Quarter
862425,05,2020,3333.33,Quarter
862425,06,2020,3333.33,Quarter
```

(b).Similarly, whenever the `PAY_TYPE` is `Bi-Annual`, I have to split the record into 6, with each record having values of `FEES` as 60000/6 = 10000 and `ACH_MONTH` being the respective months of that bi-annual.

For example,

Consider the 3rd record,

Here, `ACH_MONTH` is 02 means February which is present in the first half of the year.

Now devide value of `FEES` with 6 i.e., 60000/6 = 10000.

Now Split the record to 6 with each value `ACH_MONTH` denoting each respective month of the 1st half of the year like so,

```
862426,01,2020,10000,Bi-Annual
862426,02,2020,10000,Bi-Annual
862426,03,2020,10000,Bi-Annual
862426,04,2020,10000,Bi-Annual
862426,05,2020,10000,Bi-Annual
862426,06,2020,10000,Bi-Annual
```

Final Expected Output based on the above input dataframe,

```
CLASS_ID,ACH_MONTH,ACH_YEAR,FEES,PAY_TYPE
862424,06,2020,1000,Month
862425,04,2020,3333.33,Quarter
862425,05,2020,3333.33,Quarter
862425,06,2020,3333.33,Quarter
862426,01,2020,10000,Bi-Annual
862426,02,2020,10000,Bi-Annual
862426,03,2020,10000,Bi-Annual
862426,04,2020,10000,Bi-Annual
862426,05,2020,10000,Bi-Annual
862426,06,2020,10000,Bi-Annual
```

Quarter Reference,

```
January(01), February(02), March(03) -- (Q1)
April(04), May(05), June(06) -- (Q2)
July(07), August(08), September(09) -- (Q3)
October(10), November(11), December(12) -- (Q4)
```

Bi-Annual Reference,

```
January(01), February(02), March(03), April(04), May(05), June(06) -- (H1)
July(07), August(08), September(09), October(10), November(11), December(12) -- (H2)
```

Any and all help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is create 2 dictionaries for each quarters and bi annual by nested dict comprehensions, filter rows by `PAY_TYPE` and use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), then divide columns by `3` or `6` and last use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
q = [["01", "02", "03"],["04", "05", "06"],["07", "08", "09"],["10", "11", "12"]]
dq = {y: tuple(x) for x in q for y in x}
# print (dq)

b = [["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06"],["07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"]]
db = {y: tuple(x) for x in b for y in x}
# print (db)

m1 = df['PAY_TYPE'].eq('Quarter')
df.loc[m1, 'ACH_MONTH'] = df.loc[m1, 'ACH_MONTH'].map(dq)
df.loc[m1, 'FEES'] /= 3

m2 = df['PAY_TYPE'].eq('Bi-Annual')
df.loc[m2, 'ACH_MONTH'] = df.loc[m2, 'ACH_MONTH'].map(db)
df.loc[m2, 'FEES'] /= 6

df = df.explode('ACH_MONTH').reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
print (df)
   CLASS_ID ACH_MONTH  ACH_YEAR          FEES   PAY_TYPE
0    862424        06      2020   1000.000000      Month
1    862425        04      2020   3333.333333    Quarter
2    862425        05      2020   3333.333333    Quarter
3    862425        06      2020   3333.333333    Quarter
4    862426        01      2020  10000.000000  Bi-Annual
5    862426        02      2020  10000.000000  Bi-Annual
6    862426        03      2020  10000.000000  Bi-Annual
7    862426        04      2020  10000.000000  Bi-Annual
8    862426        05      2020  10000.000000  Bi-Annual
9    862426        06      2020  10000.000000  Bi-Annual
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand the constraint correctly

Never used DataFrame, but if you can initialize a DataFrame object from dictionary or some other way, this way should work

```
# make mappings of both quarter and bi-annual
quarters = {
  "Q1": ["01", "02", "03"],
  "Q2": ["04", "05", "06"],
  "Q3": ["07", "08", "09"],
  "Q4": ["10", "11", "12"],
}

biannual = {
  "B1": ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06"],
  "B2": ["07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"]
}

# find matching biannual or quarters based on the month mapped on its values
def find(ach_month, q_or_b):
  result = None
  for key in q_or_b:
    value = q_or_b[key]
    try:
      # check if the ach_month exists in current iteration, if not ValueError is raised
      value.index(ach_month)
      result = value
      break
    except ValueError:
      # if not found, proceed to next iteration
      pass
  # if the data is not normalized, it may returns None
  return result

# returns list of new dataframe object if it satisfies the constraint
def remap(obj):
  if obj.pay_type == "Quarter":
    quart = find(obj.ach_month, quarters)
    return [DataFrame({}) for q in quart]
  if obj.pay_type == "Bi-Annual":
    bian = find(obj.ach_month, biannual)
    return [DataFrame({}) for b in bian]
  return [obj]
```

the {} is filled with new property of the record that you want.